# Trying to extract numbers from a .txt document and sum it using regular expressions in python2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Below is my code:

```
import re
fname = raw_input ("Enter the file name: ")
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print "File name entered is not correct"   
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
print x
number = map(int, x)
print sum(number)
```

I get an empty list and total sum as zero. Not sure where am I making the mistake. I am using Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use the numbers in the last line, which contains in your case probably no numbers. You have to keep the numbers of all lines:

```
import re
fname = raw_input("Enter the file name: ")
numbers = []
with open(fname) as lines:
    for line in lines:
        numbers.extend(re.findall('[0-9]+', line))
print numbers
print sum(map(int, numbers))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the modified version. Your code works great!. However, could you please explain where exactly I am going wrong with my code? I understand that its only keeping numbers in the last line but how should I avoid that? Is there any way of doing that without creating an empty list in the beginning and then extending it?

Comment: @studentoflife: you can also build the sum at once. For me, it seemed you want to see all numbers before summing them up.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is replaced every iteration through your loop. It only retains the last line, which looks to be empty.

Comment: How should I avoid that?

Answer (score -1):

You're overwriting your variable `x` every iteration. A possible solution would be

```
import re
fname = raw_input ("Enter the file name: ")
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print "File name entered is not correct"  
    exit()
sum = 0 
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    sum += int(x[0])
print sum
```

Comment: `int` is not defined for lists.